How to study the waves created by throwing a stone into the pond?
I throw a stone into the still water and want to study the propagation of waves. That is the velocity of propagation. The waves must be circular. But how does one find the radius of the circle at each time?
Newton's third law of motion says that the force exerted by the stone creates circular waves.
Newton's second law of motion says that the stone creates force and produces waves. The mass of the stone creates a bigger force.
From the point where the stone impacts the water, I consider the force vector F to all directions. Since the magnitude of vectors F is equal, the wave is circular. Now I am stuck. How do I find the radius of the circle?

Voting to reopen. Obviously not a homework question.


The waves must be circular ...

Not necessarily. The stone will create a series of waves or ripples that will spread out from the point of impact roughly in circles, but there may be factors that make the ripples non-circular.
The shape, speed and amplitude (height) of the ripples will depend on many factors, including the size and shape of the stone, the speed and angle at which it hits the water, and the depth of the water.
You can see that waves in water do not all move at a single, constant speed by watching how waves arrive on a beach.

to add onto this: assuming the stone hits the water from a perfectly vertical trajectory the first wavefront generated will have a shape very similar to the shape of the stone, and the further the waves propagate, the more they will become circular. the circular wave is then analgous to the far field approximation of a radiating dipole in classical electrodynamics

Now assuming that the stone is circular, it hits the water orthogonally and the pond is deep enough, and of course, we have the same conditions throughout the pond, the wavefronts are circular! Isn't it? Then how does one find the radius of circle, for instance after one second?

@majid If the water depth $h$ is shallow compared to the wavelength of the waves then the speed of gravity waves is $\sqrt{gh}$. If the water is deep then gravity waves have two different speeds - a phase speed and a group speed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave for more details.
